# When to close sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

If I close the application the socket will automatically close as well or do I need to specify that if the user close the application to close the socket stream as well?

Also another question. I wanted to ask related to sockets: if I connect to an IP via sockets shouldn't I be able to see that I'm connected to it via the resource monitor in the task manager? Because I've connected to a host using its IP and open port and I don't see it on the TCP connection list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the application terminates, the socket will close.  Ideally you should close the socket when you're done using it.  Keep in mind if you don't properly close or flush the socket before terminating your application, any data in the buffer or stream attached to the socket may not be sent.

Comment: I mean if I just running the application using the ide not finished project and I stop it from running the socket will close yes ? also could you please help me with my second question ? thanks alot !

Comment: Yes, as long as the process is terminated the socket will be closed.  It doesn't matter if you terminate it from the IDE, Task Manager, or if it terminates gracefully.  Assuming the connection is successful, I would expect it to show up in the TCP Connections list (though given the list's name, I would assume it won't show up if you're using UDP). You can also try running netstat -a from the command-line.